# Using python to remove Gaussian noise and a high frequency signal from a audio file

Tags: python, filtering, audio-processing

I have an audio file where people are talking, and Gaussian noise and high-frequency signals have been added to the file. My goal is to remove the noise from this file using Python. For this assignment, I am not allowed to use ML, so that really limits my options. Does anyone have any tips on the best ways to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: I think showing the spectrogram will help you get the most complete answers